# Theano scan: how do I have a tuple output as input into next step?

Tags: theano

I want to do this sort of loop in Theano:

```
def add_multiply(a,b, k):
    return a+b+k, a*b*k, k

x=1
y=2
k=1
tuples = []
for i in range(5):
    x,y,k = add_multiply(x,y,k)
    tuples.append((x,y,k))
```

However, when I do

```
x0 = T.dvector('x0')
i = T.iscalar('i')
results,updates=th.scan(fn=add_multiply,outputs_info=[{'initial':x0,'taps':[-1]}],n_steps=i)
```

I get `TypeError: add_multiply() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)`.  If I change it so that the function takes a single tuple instead, `I get ValueError: length not known`

In particular, I eventually want to differentiate the entire result with respect to k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is because your `add_multiply` function takes 3 arguments but, by having only one element in the `outputs_info` list, you're only providing a single argument. It's not clear if you intended the `x0` vector to be the initial value for just `a` or were expecting it to be spread over `a`, `b`, and `k`. The latter isn't supported by Theano and, in general, tuples are not supported by Theano. In Theano, everything needs to be a tensor (e.g. scalars are just special types of tensors with zero dimensions).

You can achieve a replica of the Python implementation in Theano as follows.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt


def add_multiply(a, b, k):
    return a + b + k, a * b * k


def python_main():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    k = 1
    tuples = []
    for i in range(5):
        x, y = add_multiply(x, y, k)
        tuples.append((x, y, k))
    return tuples


def theano_main():
    x = tt.constant(1, dtype='uint32')
    y = tt.constant(2, dtype='uint32')
    k = tt.scalar(dtype='uint32')
    outputs, _ = theano.scan(add_multiply, outputs_info=[x, y], non_sequences=[k], n_steps=5)
    g = theano.grad(tt.sum(outputs), k)
    f = theano.function(inputs=[k], outputs=outputs + [g])
    tuples = []
    xvs, yvs, _ = f(1)
    for xv, yv in zip(xvs, yvs):
        tuples.append((xv, yv, 1))
    return tuples


print 'Python:', python_main()
print 'Theano:', theano_main()
```

Note that in the Theano version, all the tuple handling happens outside Theano; Python has to convert from the three tensors returned by the Theano function into a list of tuples.

**Update:**

It's unclear what "the entire result" should refer to but the code has been updated to show how you might differentiate with respect to `k`. Note that in Theano the symbolic differentiation only works with scalar expressions, but can differentiate with respect to multi-dimensional tensors.

In this update the `add_multiply` method no longer returns `k` since that is constant. For similar reasons, the Theano version now accepts `k` as a `non_sequence`.

Comment: One issue though.  As in the OP, "I eventually want to differentiate the entire result with respect to k," so I don't need to deal with tuples, but would like to have as my output some theano data structure that allows me to do T.grad(output, k), where output is the trajectory of x,y,k.  How could I do that?

Comment: Answer updated with info on how to do the differentiation.